# GoogleVR 1.0.1: stereo cameras are OK in the Unity Game View but too separated when compiled to Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, stereo-3d, google-vr

I'd say the value I have to change is the stereoMultiplier of the StereoController script attached to the main camera. Anyway I think I have changed every single value of GvrViewer, MainCamera and StereoController. Nothing seems to change the separation of the left and right cameras when compiled to the Android smartphone.

I can see a correct separation in the Unity Game View, but when I compile it to the smartphone, the cameras are too separated (see image below).

I think this issue has happened after updating the Smartphone to Android 6.0 Marshmallow (CyanogenMod 13.0), on Samsung S4.

---

**UPDATE**: I have updated to GoogleVR 1.0.1. The same problem is still happening.

[image: separation differences between Unity emulator and my real Android device]

Comment: Did you change any of the VR settings or are you using the defaults?

Comment: @Hrusilov I have deleted the parent prefab to use to default one coming with GoogleVR0.8.0. Same issue. However it seems the demo scene coming with GoogleVR0.8.0 is visualized well in the Android device. What could make it is correctly showed in the Unity Game View but wrongly in the Android device? :/

Comment: one of the fixes of v0.9 is Stereo separation is correctly applied to the GvrEye component in Start(), rather than only after a Resume(). This bug was not visible (or a problem) when using the now-deprecated prefabs. So hopefully it is a bug, and it will be removing after updating...

Comment: Usually had problems with the view on device when I "played" too much with the original settings and corrected it by recreating the scene from the demo scene again :)

Comment: @Hrusilov I hope to have to recreate everything again! I have updated to the latest GoogleVR version (1.0.1). Same problem.

Comment: The separation line between eyes is also cut. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing scale to 0.007 (which is a very similar scale to the objects in the provided demo scene of GoogleVR: 0.003) seems to fix the problem.

Note: discussed here: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/351

---

UPDATE: in the previous link, somebody wrote:

Android app:
/sdcard/Cardboard/current_device_params

all gvr(cardboard) app will use this file --- "current_device_params".

maybe you should go the url to setup your device profile https://vr.google.com/cardboard/viewerprofilegenerator/

in addiation, you can also do this:

[How to change Field of View in Google VR SDK for Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340898/how-to-change-field-of-view-in-google-vr-sdk-for-unity/40358587#40358587)