# How to change Field of View in Google VR SDK for Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I created a AR stuff with Google VR SDK for Unity and NyARToolkit (http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wp/?page_id=198).

Current AR screen of application, however, is not fullscreen. I wanted to change Field of View of "Camera Left" and "Camera Right", but these didn't effect on screen. How should I change to fullscreen?

Answer (score 1):

To change the Field Of View of Google VR SDK, folow these steps :

1) First select the **Main Camera** in GVR Main

[image]

2) Make changes to **Stereo Controller Script** from **Inspector** (Change values of **Match Mono FOV** & **Match By Zoom** according to your requirements)

[image]

3) Now run scene and change **Field Of View** value of **Main Camera**, and you will see effect on screen.

[image]

Hope this will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used Legacy/Prefabs/GvrHead. I set "Match Mono FOV" to 1 and "Match By Zoom" to 1 in Stereo Controller option.
It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Also ran into this problem weeks ago. Sometimes, you have to modify the `stereoMultiplier` too. Here is a simple function I use to fix this problem:

```
void fixFieldOfView(float stereoMultiplier = 1, float zoom = 0f, float fov = 0f)
{
    StereoController stereoCtrl = GvrViewer.Controller;
    stereoCtrl.stereoMultiplier = stereoMultiplier;
    stereoCtrl.matchByZoom = zoom;
    stereoCtrl.matchMonoFOV = fov;
}
```

Usage:

```
fixFieldOfView(1, 1, 1);
```

Comment: I believe you would also need `steroController.UpdateStereoValues ();` after  the matching to update the values and refresh the controller.